# Why does gvim read /usr/share/vim/vimrc instead of ~/.vim/vimrc

Tags: vimrc, linux, startup

`:help startup` states, under `3. Execute Ex commands, from environment variables and/or files` that (for Unix systems) `$HOME/.vimrc or $HOME/.vim/vimrc` is read and that `The files are searched in the order specified above and only the first one that is found is read.`

I *do* have a (read/writeable) ~/.vim/vimrc file, so I have expected this file to be read first.

However, when I start `gvim` (debugged with the `-V20` flag) I see that gvim first reads `/usr/share/vim/vimrc`. When it is finished reading this file, it *then* reads my `~/.vim/vimrc` file. I don't want the `/usr/share/vim/vimrc` file to be read at all.

The environment variable `$VIM` is not set.

Interestingly (and somewhat surprisingly for me): after gvim is started up fully, `:echo $MYVIMRC` prints `/home/rene/.vim/vimrc`.

So, my questions are: why does it behave differently from what is stated in the help file and how do I make sure that only `~/.vim/vimrc` is read.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reading system-level configuration before user-level configuration is totally normal and expected in UNIX land.

Anyway, this sentence:

```
The files are searched in the order specified above and only the first one
that is found is read.
```

only applies to "personal initializations".

As explained a few paragraphs below, the system `vimrc` is read no matter what:

```
b. For Unix, MS-DOS, MS-Windows, OS/2, VMS, Macintosh, RISC-OS and Amiga
   the system vimrc file is read for initializations.  The path of this
   file is shown with the ":version" command.  Mostly it's "$VIM/vimrc".
   Note that this file is ALWAYS read in 'compatible' mode, since the
   automatic resetting of 'compatible' is only done later.  Add a ":set
   nocp" command if you like.
```

Comment: Oh, ok, I understand.